# Multiple Y-axis labels in a MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

OK for example the numeric value of one of my data is large and the numeric value of one of my data is small.

```
A = [130000 310000 200000 400000]';
B = [16 32 5 10]';
```

I am doing the following.

```
figure;
bar(1:4,[A B],0.5,'stack');
```

Since the value of `A` is lot high than `B`, I want a secondary `y`-axis. Otherwise the values of `B` cannot be seen on the stacked bar chart.

Comment: Please provide what you have already tried out and describe more accurately the desired result.

Comment: Oddly enough, I think I understood your question. [This](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/167359) might help. I had tried the `MY_XTICKLABELS` function a while back and it had worked fine, though it wasn't exactly easy to use.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plotyy` to plot two bar charts on different y-axes in the same figure.

```
x = [1,2,3];
y1 = [1000,2000,3000];
y2 = [0.5,0.3,0.1];
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(x, y1, x, y2, 'bar', 'bar');
set(H1, 'FaceColor', [1 0 0], 'BarWidth', 1)
```

This isn't a stacked bar chart like you had before (one set of data vertically on top of the other) but it doesn't make sense include data on different scales in a stacked bar chart.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Can we also customize it as I wanted?

Comment: How do you want to customize it?

Comment: I mean is it possible to have the same Barwidth?

Comment: Sure, but if your bars are about the same height, they'll be difficult to see. You can use (H1, 'BarWidth', 1) and set(H2, 'BarWidth', 1) to control the bar width.  Just change "1" to different values.